# In container-grid, selected cell data is not getting updated if there are 2 different grids but sharing single method to update

Tags: angular, drag-to-select

Here is stackblitz url
Editor url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-drag-to-select-mcmmtg?file=src/app/app.component.html
Application url : https://ngx-drag-to-select-mcmmtg.stackblitz.io

[Dual container-grid selection-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh1EW.png)

suppose we select Document1 cell from First container-grid then in selectedIds section  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh1EW.png)  will appear as result, then if we select Document2 cell from second container-grid then in selectedIds section [ 2 ] will appear as result but again if we select Document1 from First container-grid then in selectedIds section  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh1EW.png)  should appear but it will showing second container-grid result.

Note : If we select cell again which was previously selected in container-grid then selection is getting ignored , if we select another cell for this grid then it is working fine.

Expected result : cell should be selected again and result should get updated

Comment: That's because the `selectedItemsChange` output is only triggered when a selection changes. You have to enable item deselection. Look in the documentation of the library to do so.

Comment: Is there any way to deselect cell of 1st container-grid if we select cell of 2nd container-grid ?

Comment: Probably, I'm not familiar with the library so you'd have to look at the documentation